# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '': Document is already detached

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am iterating through an array to send a request to an api to get lat and long coordinates, but am only getting one lat and long coordinate returned and then getting this error

> NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '': Document is already detached.

The code I am using is

```
function GetEachUsersLatLongCoordinates(zips) {
    return (TryCatch(function () {
        let result;
        let results = [];

        let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for (let i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    result = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.response);
                    results.push(result.results[0].geometry.location);
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + parseInt(zips[i]) + "&key=" + GoogleAPIKEY + "", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);            
        }        

        return results;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Well you have another issue treating an asynchronous request as synchronous. You really need to rethink your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @epascarello, i am trying to rethink what i wrote and looking at the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

Place the:

```
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Inside the loop.

And you can't return the result there as it's run async. You could pass a callback to GetEachUsersLatLongCoordinates or return a promise instead.

Comment: I removed the true from the open, and get an error on this results.push(result.results[0].geometry.location); geometry is undefined

Comment: Check the response of the api call